# Prisma Storing Image over 1 mb giving Server has closed the connection

Tags: node.js, express, prisma

I am trying to store image as blob using Prisma.
On schema I have stored image as Bytes @db.MediumBlob, which has approximately 16MB. If I upload image less than 1 mb they are stored, if they are more than 1 mb is gives the error displayed below.

```
   const imagesToCreate = [];

          for (const file of filesToUpload) {
            console.log(file);
            const fileData = fs.readFileSync(file.filepath);
            imagesToCreate.push({
              image: fileData,
            });
            isFirstImage = false;
          }

          await prisma.vehicle_Images.createMany({
            data: imagesToCreate,
          });
}
```

Image less than 1 mb is stored correctly, if its more it gives this error:

```
Error during image upload:  PrismaClientKnownRequestError: 
Invalid `prisma.vehicle_Images.createMany()` invocation:


Server has closed the connection.
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

mysql by default has max_allowed_packet to 1MB.
You can go to bin/myini and update value of max_allowed_packet to the value you need.